# Students learning algebraic topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question, learning

In the preface of their book "*Homotopical topology*", *Anatoly Fomenko* and *Dimitry Fuchs* say:"**Still, one can say that, from the students’ point of view, algebraic topology can now
be seen as a completed domain, and it is possible to study it from the beginning to the
end.**"
I was wondering what do they mean by studying algebraic topology from the beginnig to the end?
I think answer to this question by people who have some experience in algebraic topology can help those who start learning the subject. Thanks in advance for answers and clarifications.

Comment: My guess is they mean that you don't have to go to original source papers (or non-textbook survey papers) to learn what is needed in algebraic topology for any other field, or to even to begin research in algebraic topology (which would only require appropriate specialized papers for current research at the fringes of the subject). It would have helped if they gave two or three examples to help clarify what they mean.

Comment: It's hard/impossible to guess what authors might mean by statements like that. Furthermore, the first edition of that book is many decades old, so assuming that statement to be present in the first edition, whatever meaning it might have had at the time is probably entirely outdated now.

Comment: @Lee Mosher Funnily enough I don't see this phrase in the old edition.

Comment: I was wondering about that. Nonetheless, the comment is fathomless to me even if written recently. @АрсенийКряжев